# is it possible that "any of the miners would survive" is used, instead of "any of the miners had survived"?

Tags: tense

> On October 13, 2010, thirty three Chilean miners who had been buried
> inside the San José mine for 69 days were finally rescued. It was a
> triumph of engineering and a victory of faith. The miners locked in
> below did not give up in the dark, nor did their families above ground
> surrender to despair. On August 5, 2010, at around lunch break, miners
> digging for copper and gold started to feel vibrations in the earth.
> Almost immediately after the vibrations began, they heard a sudden
> huge explosion, and the whole mine filled up with dust and rock. A
> massive piece of the nearby mountain had broken off, burying almost
> all the layers of the mine. For seventeen days after the initial
> collapse, there was no word on their fate. As the days passed,
> Chileans grew increasingly uncertain that **any of the miners had
> survived**. A small exploratory hole was drilled on August 22, and the
> camera captured a message that said, "We are still alive." It was the
> first sign of hope. Soon, a video camera was sent down 700 meters deep
> and captured the first images of the miners, all clearly in good
> health. The discovery sparked joyful celebrations nationwide, and
> rescue efforts gave a light of hope that the miners could be saved.

I felt a little weird at the bold clause. why did the author use the tense "had pp"??
is it possible that "any of the miners would survive" is used, instead of "any of the miners had survived"?

Comment: They weren't certain that any of the miners were not (already) dead. "Would survive" refers to the future at that time.

Comment: @Michael Harvey I think he misinterpreted Korean into English. (~할 거라고 확신하다) or he thinks any of the miners would be saved from the depth. Definitely, “would”is not that unnatural in the context.

Comment: I can't understand this phrase "any of the miners were not (already) dead"... ㅠㅠ

Comment: When Michael Harvey wrote "They weren't certain that any of the miners were not (already) dead", he was paraphrasing your quote, "[they] grew increasingly uncertain that any of the miners had survived".

Comment: Ahhh... I'm sorry. I misunderstood Chileans as miners in bold phrase. So I can't understand the tense, but now I definitely understand! thank you my online teachers :)

Answer (score 2):

Either tense works just fine, but they mean different things.

**They grew uncertain that any of the miners had survived**

This tense is called the pluperfect (it has other names as well). It says that miners' survival is in the past, relative to the Chileans' growing uncertain.

Another example of the pluperfect: "By the time I reached the railway station, the train had already left". That means the train left *before* I arrived.
So, back to the Chilean miner situation, at the time the Chileans are growing uncertain, they were asking themselves, "Have they survived?"

**They grew uncertain that any of the miners would survive**

This tense is for saying "something hypothetically happening some time after something which is in the past". So at the time the Chileans are growing uncertain, they were asking themselves, "Will they survive?"

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation :) I want to get some further explanation about "Have  they survived?". is it possible that I think "before they 'grew' uncertain, they 'had cast' their survival possibility?

Comment: @dongyoungkim What do you mean?

Comment: Ahhh... I'm sorry. I misunderstood Chileans as miners in bold phrase. So I can't understand the tense, but now I definitely understand! thank you my online teacher :)